# Angular bindings with resolve in views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router

How can I pass data using resolve and bindings to component in views? It worked well when I was passing data to controller but with component it doesn't work.

```
      .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('stState', {
            url: '/state',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
              label: 'State'
            },
            views: {
              '': {
                component: 'stState'
              }
            },
            resolve: {
              data: function (dataService) {
                return dataService.getData();
              }
            }
          });
      })

      .component('stState', {
        templateUrl: 'app/stState/stState.html',
        controller: StStateController,
        bindings: {
          data: '<'
        }
      });

    function StStateController() {
       this.data = {};
    }
```

Comment: works [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5RtBwBOZPXuUU3X4te18?p=preview) which is almost similar to your example

Comment: Why do you have `views:` when you want to route to a component?

Answer (score 0):

you will get `data` as a service and will have to inject it into your controller. just the way you do for `$scope`

```
function StStateController(data) {
   this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: It returns data is unknown provider

Answer (score 0):

UI router only injects instances into the view (state) controllers it manages. Your options are:

1. Inject `data` into your view controller and put it on the `$scope`, then pass it to your component via an attribute binding.
2. OR: Create a service, let's say `MyDirectiveDataService`, that your component knows about (at this point your component would have to be a fully-fledged directive with a controller of its own) and then inject `MyDirectiveDataService` into the view controller and use the controller to call `MyDirectiveDataService.setData(data)`. This approach may have weird side effects if you don't have clear separation of concerns, but it will work.

Something I would avoid doing altogether is using a component as a $state view. Again, due to separation of concerns.